Reference currently presented view controller
im working on a method to go to to a particular screen within my app on deep link and need to acheieve this from scene delegate.
The current heirarchy is as follows:
UITabViewController
UIViewController in tab 1 (Dashboard)
UIViewController (Login) presented modally full screen from Dashboard (not in a navigation controller) on top of everything.
Id like reference to the currently presented modal so i can take action from it programmatically.  That is where my problems are.  I cannot seem to get reference to the modal.  The deepest reference i can find is the view controller on tab 1.
i tried
func getTopViewController()->UIViewController{
    return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!)
}
func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController:UIViewController)->UIViewController{
    if rootViewController is UITabBarController{
        let tabBarController = rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController!)
    }
    if rootViewController is UINavigationController{
        let navBarController = rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navBarController.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
} 

the following prints out nil
if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
           let dashboardViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? AccountDashboardViewController{
            print("presented controller", dashboardViewController.presentedViewController)
}

what else can i do to get reference to the presented view controller, and not the one in the tab bar?

How did you present the modal? Presumably you called someVC.present(anotherVC, animated: true) - what is someVC here?

That is right.  someVC is AccountDashboardViewController (the view controller on tab 1) in this case.  I can get reference to this controller (the dashboard), but not the controller presented on top of it.

The method to get the top view controller provided in the original question is accurate, but what happens is a modal takes some time to become the top controller.  If you check the top controller immediately when your deep link is called in scene delegate it will identify the view controller responsible for presenting the modal as the top, because at that time it really was the top.  Solution is adding a slight delay before checking to allow the modal time to open:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
    if let topViewController = self.getTopViewController() {
       print("Top View Controller: \(topViewController)")
    }
})

